# Moving ASP.NET 1.1 site to IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am trying to move an asp.net 1.1 site that is currently hosted on a dying server with IIS 6 to a new server with IIS 7. I've setup everything with IIS to get the asp.net 1.1 app pool and classic mode and all that good stuff. When I access the site though, I keep getting

```
    Parser Error 

Could not load type 'XXX.Type

    <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="default.aspx.vb" Inherits="XXX.Type" EnableViewState="False" %>
```

I don't have access to the source code. What should I do to get this running?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Not 100% sure but i believe CodeBehind is replaced with CodeFile to specify the source file in ASP.NET 2.0 and up.

Comment: The site is asp.net 1.1, the app pool is set to asp.net 1.1

Comment: @Pranay You're thinking of IIS 6

Comment: @ILovePaperTowels dude, migrate it to one of the later versions if you can. Seriously!

Comment: @ILovePaperTowels also see this page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc531167.aspx It is highly possible it is gonna be dead soon.

Comment: @tugberk Did you not read my question? 1) I don't have access to the source code (neither does the client) 2) I just need to move the site. It doesn't matter if it wont be supported in 2 years. These are the restrictions I have to work with. Obviously if I could change them I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing dll in a bin folder for the XXX.Type class which default.aspx.vb inherits from

Comment: Are the COM DLL's registered on the new machine with Regsvr32.exe?

Comment: maybe the dll has a dependency on another dll which is not on the server. I would use process monitor tool http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals to see what w3wp.exe is trying to load.

Comment: @Andrew I'm looking at the dll via ILSpy and i'm not seeing the XXX.Type so I have to investigate and see if I pulled the right files from the right server. I don't think there are any DLL's in the GAC but i'll have to look again.

Comment: I award you the answer because it's the closest. If you can have a look at my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557086/asp-net-1-1-web-site-inherits-from-non-existent-class i'd appreciate it.